# Two @XmlJavaTypeAdapters for one @XmlAttribute in JAXB?

Tags: java, jaxb

I have a class like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "PricingGroup")
public class PricingGroup {

    ...

    @XmlAttribute(name = "partyName")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CustomerGroupRelationships.Adapter.class)
    private List<BilltoCustomer> billtoCustomers = new ArrayList<BilltoCustomer>();

    @XmlAttribute(name = "partyName")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(PartyNames.Adapter.class)
    private PartyName partyName;  

    ...  
}
```

It seems JAXB can't map two `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter`s for one attribute (here `partyName`). If I comment out either the annotations on billtoCustomers or the annotations on partyName, the other member variable is read from XML without problems.

How can I get both values at the same time?

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you map two fields to the same attribute?

Comment: I'm reading only from XML. And adding `@XmlTransient` to one of the fields doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could map one of the properties (`partyName`) and then use an `afterUnmarshal` event to derive the other property (`billToCustomers`):

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "PricingGroup")
public class PricingGroup {

    ...

    @XmlTransient    
    private List<BilltoCustomer> billtoCustomers = new ArrayList<BilltoCustomer>();

    @XmlAttribute(name = "partyName")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(PartyNames.Adapter.class)
    private PartyName partyName;  


   void afterUnmarshal(Unmarshaller u, Object parent) {
      // Derive billToCustomers from partyName
   }

    ...  
}
```